# Bindingsource won't update after the textbox Conrol updates

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a form which its controls are binded to a bindingsrource named "userbindingsource". When the form loads all the value in bindingsrource will be set to equivalent Textbox. But when the textboxes values change , the bindingsrource won't update. and still it shows the very first value

[image]

For example after load I change the first name in textbox and then click save Button to call the saveRecord(). when I check (userBindingSource.DataSource as User) , it still contains the first firstname without any changes.

```
 public void SaveRecord()
    {
        int i = 0;
        User user = userBindingSource.DataSource as User;
        if (user.Id > 0)
            user.State = State.Modified;
        using (ECarServiceClient client = new ECarServiceClient())
        {
            i = client.SaveUser(user);
        }
    }
```

how can make the bindingsource updates automatically?

Comment: Does the User.FirstName property have a public setter?

Comment: @jnm2: yes it has

Comment: Ah, I have a guess. If the textbox binding has DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation (the default) and you go right from typing in a textbox to clicking the Save button, the Save click is handled before the textbox validates which is what makes it update the BindingSource and User object.

The fix would be to call [`this.Validate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.validate?view=netframework-4.8) at the beginning of SaveRecord, I think.

Comment: @jnm2:That was correct. please post it  as an answer , so I can vote you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the textbox binding has [`DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datasourceupdatemode?view=netframework-4.8#fields) (the default) and you go right from typing in a textbox to clicking the Save button, the Save click is handled before the textbox validates. Validation is what makes the BindingSource update the User object.

The fix would be to call [`this.Validate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.validate?view=netframework-4.8) at the beginning of SaveRecord. This triggers validation of the focused control within the current form and all its ancestors.